# Center the div with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want center the pricing box you can see it from http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.1/pricing.html

I applied the found solution from other posts,

I tried add the following css on the `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 pricing-box">`

```
  float:none;
  // width: 1200px;
  display: block;
  //margin-left: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

But the pricing box still stick to the left border, not be centered

Comment: can you put your code in js fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/?
As your question is difficult to comprehend .

Answer (score 0):

You can center a div by using the following css style:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Because you have a fixed margin-left of 200px, then it won't be always on the middle, it might be in the middle when the margin-left and margin-right are both 200px, but that wouldn't happen very often.

Comment: Sorry , I posted the wrong code. actually, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the four boxes side by side? You want them to be centered and beneath each other?

If so, then

```
.pricing-box {
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If this is not the case you'll need to give more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using offsetting if you are using Bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting